# Strong parameters: extending a controller and want to add required params to existing ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, strong-parameters

I have the following controller:

```
class BoilerplatesController < InheritedResources::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource

  private

  def boilerplate_params
    params.require(:boilerplate).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

Then I extend it with this one:

```
class BoilerplateCopiesController < BoilerplatesController
  defaults instance_name:  'boilerplate',
           resource_class: BoilerplateCopy

  private

  def boilerplate_params
    params.require(:boilerplate).permit(findings_attributes: [:id, :url])
    super
  end
end
```

It seems that the extending one doesn't add the new fields to the existing ones, but overrules them. How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (or workaround) would be:

BoilerplatesController:

```
def boilerplate_params
  params.require(:boilerplate).permit(required_params)
end

def required_params
  [:title,
   :intro,
   :lock_version,
   :outro,
   :resources,
   :topic_id,
   :tags,
   :how_to_evaluate,
   :status,
   :priority]
end
```

BoilerplateCopiesController:

```
def required_params
  super << {findings_attributes: [:id,
                                  :url,
                                  :description,
                                  :screenshot,
                                  :remove_screenshot]
           }
end
```

Comment: Is there really no other solution?